# WPF TabItem content not displaying data

Tags: wpf, tabitem

I have a problem with TabItem content not displaying data until I click on another TabItem and then I click back to the first TabItem.
I understand WPF TabItems might use virtualization and that not visible TabItems are disabled.
Though, I am talking about the visible TabItem on startup.

More details:
My main window is composed of a TabControl.
This TabControl ContentTemplate is composed of a user control.
This user control is also composed of a TabControl.

In both the main window and the user control I set the property SelectedIndex="0".

When I start the application, the visible TabItem is not displaying data.
Though I can see that the thread displaying data is running.
If I click on another TabItem and then back on the first TabItem then the data are displayed correctly.

So my question is: what should I do display the data in the visible TabItem on the application startup ?

Some code:

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Appname.Views.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Appname.Views"
    xmlns:race="clr-namespace:Appname.Controls.Race"
    xmlns:emc="clr-namespace:Appname.Controls.ExpandingMenu"
    xmlns:control="clr-namespace:Appname.Controls"
    xmlns:wpft="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="appname" Height="800" Width="1024">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="224" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="4" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <!--Left Menu-->
    <emc:ExpandingMenuControl DataContext="{Binding ExpandingMenu}" />

    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Width="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />

    <!--Right part-->
    <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Markets}" SelectedIndex="0" Grid.Column="2" Name="TabMarkets" >
        <TabControl.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TabItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource TabStyle}" />
        </TabControl.Resources>

        <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding MarketName}" Margin="4,0" Padding="4,0" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>

        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <race:RaceControl DataContext="{Binding RaceControlViewModel }"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

RaceControl.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="Appname.Controls.Race.RaceControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Appname.Controls"
         xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:Appname.Controls"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
    <!--Races Tabs-->
    <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Races}" SelectedIndex="0" Name="TabRaces">
        <TabControl.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TabItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource TabStyle}" />
        </TabControl.Resources>

        <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=StartTime, StringFormat={}{0:HH:mm}}" Padding="4,0" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>

        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Runners, Mode=OneWay}">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <uc:SelectionControl />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
                    <!--Market Panel-->
                    <uc:MarketPanelControl Grid.Column="1" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}, Path=DataContext.MarketPanel}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

MainWindowViewModel.cs

```
private ObservableCollection<MarketModel> _markets;
public ObservableCollection<MarketModel> Markets
{
    get { return _markets; }
    set
    {
        if (_markets != value)
        {
            _markets = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

RaceControlViewModel.cs

```
    public ObservableCollection<RaceModel> Races { get; private set; }
```

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: We need some code snippets and also, elaborate a bit more on "I can see that the thread displaying data is running". Having multiple threads do have implications.

Comment: I meant that the thread that is updating the properties to which the views are bound is doing its job. There is no INP issue because it works when I switch tab items.  I will try to isolate the code and show it when I will be back at home. Thank you.

Comment: Can anybody help ?

Comment: Sorry for the long silence, I was busy abroad. I found the issue but don't really understand the root cause, it is located in the notifier class, the PropertyChangedEventHandler is null so the INPC event is not sent. I try to isolate this issue in a project.

Comment: I failed to isolate the issue in a new project .A thread is started in a DispatcherTimer at a certain time. Data are then received via an API but the UI is not updated. I found that the PropertyChangedEventHandler is null so I understand why UI data are not updated. What I don't understand is that, as soon as I switch to another TabItem and then switch back to the initial TabItem, the PropertyChangedEventHandler is not null any more and the UI data are updated. Is it a WPF bug, I don't understand what's going on when I switch back to the initial TabItem ! Can anybody help ?